# Is there a way to review your comments made in relation to questions or answers?

Tags: discussion

We have the readily accessible list of the questions we've asked or answers we've given and the votes they've received, but what about comments we've made? Is there no compilation of those comments available to us?

Comment: We could use data.stackexchange.com, but I haven't got a query to hand.

Comment: @Pureferret - caveat: data.stackexchange data isn't realtime (synced each Sunday, so could be 0-6 day lag)

Comment: Caveat caveat: @DVK no SE data is truely real-time.

Comment: @Pureferret - wow! When did that miracle happen and why was there no memo? </O'Neill>

Comment: @Pureferret -Part of what drove my query is simple curiosity about upvotes on my comments and how close am I to getting a shiny new badge :-) '10 comments with +5 votes'. Questions and Answers are readily accessible to review but comments, not so much.

Answer (score 7):

On your user page, choose activity, then comments.

Or do you want a more specific (possibly grouped) list?

Comment: Caveat: you can ONLY see non-deleted commments. There's no kept history of comments that were deleted

Comment: @DVK - does your query show deleted comments?

Comment: @SSumner - no :(  . "There's no kept history of comments that were deleted" applies to Data.Stackexchange as well.

Comment: @SQB -Yes, I was wondering about a more specific, 'grouped' list. Having all comments mixed with all questions/answers makes for a very ponderous and time consuming review of the database. Even more if your computer skills are as pitifully limited as mine are.

Comment: @Morgan It _does_ show just your comments. See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/13090/morgan?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: @SQB -Yes thanks. I did find that from your answer, but it doesn't show any vote count associated with the comments. DVK gave me a quick tutorial to access the Data Stackexchange to make a query, but I can't seem to get the commands right. I keep getting >invalid< messages.

Comment: Ah, you want the vote count. You might want to add that to your question :)

Answer (score 4):

You can run this query I just wrote on Data Stackexchange: http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/195030/all-my-comments?UserId=976

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT 
p.Id as [Post Link], 
pt.Name 'Post Type',
c.Score,
c.CreationDate,
c.Text
FROM
    Comments c, PostTypes pt, Posts p
WHERE  UserId = @UserId
  AND  p.PostTypeId = pt.Id
  AND  c.PostId = p.Id
ORDER BY 
    Score DESC
```

Comment: Change `Order By` to whatever else you want (p.ID for per-post. CASE statement based on PostTypeId for per-question)

Comment: Caveat: you can ONLY see non-deleted commments. There's no kept history of comments that were deleted.

Comment: Thanks DVK, that looks like a good start. Can it be refined to select only questions and list them in descending order of vote count? My computer aptitude and attention span most closely resembles that of a gnat so you will have to "speak slowly and enunciate clearly".

Comment: @Morgan - add "`AND  p.PostTypeId=1`" for questions only. Change "Score DESC" to "p.Vote DESC" for vote count in "Order by"

Comment: You're giving me far too much credit. My skillsets lay far outside of this environment. If you need a book written or something build/destroyed, I'm your guy. But here in this computer world you seem to navigate with such ease, I'm less than worthless. I can see that query via your hotlink but have no clue how to modify it as you suggest or to create my own query.

Comment: LOL, I even struggled with what that challenge protocol required.

Comment: @Morgan - you can always copy query text into a new query :)

Comment: I modified the query. The response I got to that query is: >Invalid column name 'PosTypeId'. Invalid column name 'Vote'.<

Comment: @morgan *PosTypeId* is a typo. You're missing a 'T' (postTypeId).

Comment: @phantom42 -Oops... did I mention that I was a computer retard? I'm sure by now that DVK is just shaking his head with a disappointed look on his face.

Comment: @Morgan No worries. It's an easy mistake to make and overlook.

Comment: I got this far http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/new but received this message >Invalid column name 'Vote'.< It's apparently not accepting  "p.Vote DESC".